# Is there any proof of warped space?

Tags: spacetime, curvature

If space is warped around the sun, wouldn't the sun act as a gravity lens? Other than the theory of GR, is there any actual proof of warped space? If the earth orbits the sun due to warped space - what proof is there of that? Gravity is the usual explanation, however a friend insists that is old school and invalid in the face of warped space.

Comment: *"If the earth orbits the sun due to warped space - what proof is there of that? Gravity is the usual explanation"*  - ???  Gravity is a given, a physical phenomenon (objects gravitate), not an explanation.  Newton's theory of gravity is based on a force (due to gravitational mass) while  Einstein's theory of gravity is based on warped space(time) (due to mass-energy).

Comment: Assuming GR is correct, gravity *literally is* distortion of spacetime. You can see the effect of this in, for example, GPS timings, which are slightly affected by the time dilation caused by Earth's mass. Similarly, Mercury's orbit is nonclassical to an extent that can be measured, owing to its proximity to the Sun's very large mass. GR has serious limitations however, for instance it cannot be straightforwardly reconciled with what we know about *small* length scales.

Comment: Wikipedia provides a page on [Tests of General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) which sounds like a good place for you to start.

Answer (score 2):

> wouldn't the sun act as a gravity lens

Yes, and it does. It's indeed a [classical test of General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Deflection_of_light_by_the_Sun).

> Other than the theory of GR, is there any actual proof of warped space?

A theory can't be a proof, but anyway, there are many [tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) the theory passed, besides predicting gravitation accurately, and allowing the GPS to work.

> a friend insists that [Gravity is] invalid in the face of warped space

In physics we often have models that are very accurate but hard to use, in which case we resort to simplifications: the simplification is not *invalid* if done adequately, it's *an approximation* that increases the usefulness of a theory.

Historically it's obviously not how it came about, but Newtonian gravity is a possible approximation of General Relativity, actually an extremely good one in its domain of validity for that matter.

So your friend is wrong.